# How can Xcode 7 Stack Views be backwards-compatible with iOS 8 and iOS 7?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uistackview

I watched the WWDC video #407 - "Implementing UI Designs in Interface Builder" that present the cool feature - "Stack Views", and I was wonder that it would be wonderful (if it is possible) to build apps that will run on iOS 7, and 8 and take advantage of the new flexible UI layout abilities that Apple has added to Xcode 7.

Comment: Unfortunately [`UIStackView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/) is not available for iOS < 9.0

Comment: `OAStackView` aims at replicating all the features in UIStackView in iOS 7+ https://github.com/oarrabi/OAStackView

Answer (score 9, accepted):

UIStackView is supported from iOS 9 onwards (iOS9 and later).

Its availability has not been mentioned for its previous version till now.
And its clearly said that its new feature for iOS9.

Hence the answer for your question is - its in not a backward-compatibility.

There is similar thing available (OAStackView) to support prior version of iOS.
https://github.com/oarrabi/OAStackView

Comment: Thanks Mithun, I tried OAStackView and it works (Big thanks for its editor - Omar Abdelhafith) , but it doesn't reflect the layout at Interface Builder Canvas at design time and not in the Assistant Editor. The predefined values for axis, alignment, distribution properties at the Inspector missing...

Comment: Can anyone explain me..How I can use this OAStackview, I used UIStackview In my project. but for earlier version of iOS9 to support what to do with my app?